# Publishing in Apple Store and Google Play

Tags: android, app-store, google-play

Apple and Google will allow us to publish three versions of each game? (One full and free for Baltic states, Next - free but not full for global market, and the last - full and for money)

Because, when project will expand, we would like to publish these games in even more versions. In other words, in those countries (markets), where local sponsors will fund us - we would like to publish these games for free (full versions). So in time these each application versions could grow in number.

So there wouldn't be any problem with this (version count)?
And the other question - will these both companies (Apple and Google) allow us to put some sponsor logos in each version? (for example Samsung, local bank, etc)

Answer (score 1):

You can upload the same game with different Name & package name. The package name renaming is mandatory, not the app name I think. You can customize the logo, UI etc in new version.

Take `Temple Run` as an example. Disney put a new version of the game, `Temple Run: Brave`.

The name & UI & package are different. `com.imangi.templerun` for `Temple Run` and `com.disney.brave_google` for `Temple Run: Brave`.

**Edit:** My answer is for only google play. Not sure about apple store.

Answer (score 0):

For Android,

Having so many apks (You will have to change the package name every-time for each of the builds you wish to update), which basically has the same codebase is tiring. I would suggest to have it taken care of by your own application, and may be with server side support.

For Apple,

As far as I know, the names should be different. Here also, depending on whether you want to handle so many builds, you might want to have a universal build targeting all kinds of audiences.

As for the sponsors, I think that's not a problem for either.